# JSONArray parsing a multidimensional array

Tags: android, json, android-json

I have an array jArray in the format :

```
{"users":[
           {
                 "user_id":6,
                 "user_name":"Ted Vanderploeg",
                 "email":"test5@test.com",
                 "additional_info":[["HP","Chief Sales Officer","","",1]]
            },
            {
                 "user_id":59,
                 "user_name":"Lindsay White",
                 "email":"test12260@test.com",
                 "additional_info":[["Microsoft","Global Head","","",1]]
             }
          ]
}
```

Now I need to get the value "Microsoft" from additional_info array. This is what I'm trying :

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {

     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jArray.getString(i));
     String workInfo = jsonObject.getString("additional_info");
     Log.i("MyActivity", "got work obj as " + workInfo.toString());
}
```

Now I get workInfo as [["Microsoft","Global Head","","",1]]. Stuck on how to proceed next, to get the value Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like a JSONArray inside a JSONArray

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jArray.getString(i));
 JSONArray workinfo = jsonObject.optJSONArray("additional_info");
   if (workinfo != null) {
        for(int j=0;j<workinfo.length();j++) {
             JSONArray values = workinfo.optJSONArray(j);
             for(int z=0;z<values.length();z++) {
                  Log.i("MyActivity", "got work obj as " + values.optString(z));
             }
        }
   }
}
```